# javascript variable returning NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

I have the following function, and don't really understand why newOutput returns NaN. I am passing 0 for newOutput as an initial value.

The first console.log returns "0"

The second console.log returns the values from arrayFinal (built earlier in my script) as a string (all numeric with no spaces--for example 1,21,322,14,18.3).

The third console.log returns undefined.

The last console.log returns NaN, as does the return statement for the function.

The point of failure is obvious, but my question is why is this function both able to convert arrayFinal into a string and unable to get the value of arrayFinal[i]?

```
function itemSum(newOutput, arrayFinal)
{
    for(i = 0; i < arrayFinal.length; i++);
    console.log(newOutput);
    console.log(arrayFinal.toString());
    newOutput = arrayFinal[i] + newOutput;
    console.log(arrayFinal[i]);
    console.log(newOutput);
    return newOutput;
};
```

edited to correct the problem

```
function itemSum(newOutput, arrayFinal)
{
    for(i = 0; i < arrayFinal.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(newOutput);
        console.log(arrayFinal.toString());
        newOutput = arrayFinal[i] + newOutput;
        console.log(arrayFinal[i]);
        console.log(newOutput);
        return newOutput;
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the data in the array?

Comment: for(i = 0; i < arrayFinal.length; i++); the last semicolon - is it intentional?

Comment: at the time of `newOutput = arrayFinal[i] + newOutput;` the variable `i` will have the value `arrayFinal.length` which returns `undefined` and added to whatever returns `NaN`

Comment: It's generate by user input and a little math. Right now arrayFinal.toString() returns 5,8,2,17.

Comment: nope. that semicolon was not intentional.

Comment: @Satyajit: The indentation seems to support that premise :-) Probably requires a completely block with curly parens, not only omitting that semicolon.

Comment: Then your "loop" doesn't do what you want it to do. Please go with @Andrew Shepherd's answer.

Comment: Yeah. I screwed up the curly braces. Thanks

Comment: @Chris - You shouldn't edit the mistake out of the question, because then the exchange won't make sense to the next person to read this.

Comment: @Andrew Shepherd - Fair point. I edited my post to include both the original block of code and a corrected block. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a set of curly braces.

Instead of:

```
 for(i = 0; i < arrayFinal.length; i++) {
    // inner code
 }
```

You've got

```
 for(i = 0; i < arrayFinal.length; i++);
 // more code
```

This first `for` line is actually an empty loop. It will increment `i` until it equals `arrayFinal.length`, and then after that loop is complete you execute the rest of the code.

Then, when you access `arrayFinal[i]`, you are looking one past the end of an array. Instead of crashing (like some languages do in this situation), javascript returns `undefined`.

And then `undefined` plus a number returns `NaN`.

Comment: Yeah. This is what happened. It isn't quite working as intended, but now it's doing something which makes sense--I just have to figure out how to tell the computer what I want it to do from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of `newOutput = arrayFinal[i] + newOutput;` the variable `i` will have the value `arrayFinal.length` and `arrayFinal[arrayFinal.length]` returns `undefined`, added to whatever this results in `NaN`. You probably meant to write:

```
function itemSum(newOutput, arrayFinal)
{
    console.log(newOutput);
    console.log(arrayFinal.toString());
    for(i = 0; i < arrayFinal.length; i++) {
        newOutput = arrayFinal[i] + newOutput;
        console.log(arrayFinal[i]);
    }
    console.log(newOutput);
    return newOutput;
}
```

or something similar

Answer (score -2):

Where are the inputs for each parameter?
Have you called the function?

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this website.